# Substitute only on certain lines

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

Is there a way to have `s;/;|;g` run only on the lines I filter using a regex?

I have a file, which looks like:

```
Date: 2017/08/18
Path /home/share/thing
Path /home/me/thing
Date: 2017/08/18
Path /home/share/thing
Date: 2017/08/18
Path /home/share/thing
Path /home/me/thing
...
```

Now this is simplified, but the point is I want to substitute the `/` on the lines beginning with `Path`, but not the ones beginning with `Date`.  I can grab all of the lines with `Path` easily enough (`:g/Path`) and substitute all of the `/`s (`:%s;/;|;g`), but for substituting on the specific lines I only know how to give `s` a range, which doesn't help much.

It seems like it would be easiest if you could pipe the output of `g` to `s`, but I couldn't find anything on doing something like that.

Comment: If you don't mind, I will use this question as an example exercise in my plugin [EXtend.vim](https://github.com/saulaxel/EXtend.vim). It just fits perfectly for the purpose of the plugin.

Comment: @SaulAxelMartinezOrtiz all content on Stack Exchange is licensed under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), so you can do what you like as long as you [provide proper attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* "pipe" the lines from `:g/` to `:s`.  Really, this is a special case of using any command after the `g//`.

```
g/Path/s;/;|;g
```

This is also documented explicitly at the bottom of the section `:help :g`

Comment: `g/^Path/s;/;|;g` lines *beginning* with `Path`, not lines *containing* it :)